# Why does a Smart Group disappear when assigned a Parent

Tags: groups, smartgroups

I'm running CiviCRM 4.7.6, and in attempt to associate an ACL with a Smart Group, I assigned my Smart Group a parent which is a static group. This seems to have worked, in that when I list the members of the static group, the members of the Smart Group are in the list, however now the Smart Group has disappeared from the list of groups.

To summarize:

1. Created Smart Group called "Current Members" that selects contacts based on their membership status
2. Created static Group "Members"
3. Assigned "Members" as the parent group for "Current Members"

Now, Static Group "Members" includes all the contacts from Smart Group "Current Members" has disappeared from the list of Groups.

Did I break some rule mixing Smart Groups and Static Groups, or is there some list of child groups I don't see?

Comment: wanna reproduce on a demo site?

Comment: Are you asking me to reproduce it on a demo site, or asking me if I'd like to reproduce it on a demo site?

Comment: @PaulDufresne This sort of attitude will not endear you to the community.

Comment: @JoAnne, I'm not sure what attitude you're referring to, as I wasn't sure what I was being asked. Is there a demo site everyone has access to? Perhaps I didn't ask for clarification very well, but I didn't understand the question.

Comment: hi Paul. yep sorry, i should have said THE demo site, and will try to remember to paste https://civicrm.org/demo

Comment: actually i realise i said 'a' demo site as there is one per CMS

Comment: @PaulDufresne - Apologies, I misinterpreted your comment as "I can't be bothered reproducing it on one of the demo sites and there is enough wiggle room in the wording of the comment ("wanna = want to and I don't 'want to'. ") for me not to have to."  10 hours ago was the very early hours of the morning for me and I should have been tucked up in bed sleeping away my cynical self, not jumping to ill-founded conclusions.

Comment: No problem. I appreciate the help, and I learned something new that will help beyond this one quirk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the manage groups screen is there a triangle to the left of the word 'Members' that expands to show the child groups when you click on it?  There should be.

Comment: No. I just went back to check, and there's no triangle to allow me to expand Members to show child groups. When I read your comment, I thought maybe I missed it, but it's not there.

Comment: So this is a problem specific to your site. The demos work fine.

Comment: So, based on your comment, I did a search for demo sites, found it and tested the theory on the demo site, and I see the little triangle on the demo site, but it's not there on my site. Now what makes my site different, I wonder.

Comment: It's strange, If I search for groups that are both Enabled and Disabled, the group appears in the list (it is enabled), and indicates it's a child of members, but not as a drop down below members. The group is there, I can search for it, it just doesn't show the drop down arrow for it's parent.

Comment: What CMS are you using? If it is wordpress can you set the theme to a standard theme such as twenty fifteen and see if the triangles are visible then?

Comment: I will check with the administrator,  he's in the process of duplicating our site on a test server for just these kinds of isssues. I will check on the theme once it's up. ThanX

Answer (score -2):

I've got exact the same problem. I upgraded to 4.7.6 from 4.6 and all the childgroups disappeared, no triangle to be seen.

Using Civicrm with Drupal. Changed layout but that didn't help.

Comment: Upgrading to 4.7.8 solved the problem for me